# Como rellenar la string con una expresión regular?

Tags: javascript, regex

**Como podría rellenar una String** con una `expresión regular`, por ejemplo:

**Que el relleno sean solo vocales, y si se acaban las vocales se repiten desde el principio** `a e i o u`

```js
var pattern = /[0-9]/;
console.log('es8'.padStart(20,pattern));
```

Obviamente que **no quiero rellenar** con la **regex LITERAL**, *sino con su función de expresion regular*. En la `MDN`, no sale si puede o no usar `regex` en el **segundo parámetro**, vease:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/padStart

Comment: ¿Cómo sería un ejemplo correcto de lo que ocupas sea tu string?

Comment: Edite la pregunta con otro ejemplo

Comment: ¿Quieres mandar una función como parámetro? Leyendo la documentación dado que es una tecnología experimental y probablemente no deberías de usarla aún, solo recibe como parámetro un string, en caso de que le envíes una variable, automáticamente se concatenará al string el resultado de hacer `pattern.toString()` lo cual regresa `'/[0-9]/'`

Comment: Entonces, aún no se puede ?

Comment: Si en lugar de poner `regex` pones `aeiou` tendrás el efecto que quieres. La función no acepta expresiones regulares solo string y no está soportada por todos los navegadores, así que no es recomendable usarla por ahora

Comment: Gracias Lato y Lixus, podrían poner de respuesta por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*La respuesta a mi pregunta fué que al ser una implementación aún experimental, esta no acepta expresiones regulares aún.*